# Getting Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/3520/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://leafground.com/select.xhtml");

      WebElement dropdown2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'j_idt87:country_label\']"));
    dropdown2.sendKeys("Germany");
```

This code is not working and getting exception. Kindly help to resolve the same.

When i ran got exception. Not sure how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way to select the `Germany` from the dropdown.

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt87:country_label"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(dropdown).click().perform();

WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-label='Germany']"));
option.click()
```

***import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Comment: To the same code i need to check confirm on the cities belong to the selected country.

Comment: Is your given issue resolved ?

Comment: Yes country got resolved. Thanks!!

Comment: So please accept the answer and ask the other question in new post.

Answer (score 0):

`select` element is hidden so you cannot directly interact with it. Try below

```
driver.get("https://leafground.com/select.xhtml");

driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt87:country_label")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-label='Germany']")).click();
```

Comment: Tried above code and worked thanks.